Cumulative Total in Bar Chart Data Studio
I am facing an issue with Bar Cumulative total by Year Month & Team level calculation. Following is example data:

And this is the output which I want in the form of column bar chart in data studio.

But the Cumulative in bar is incorrectly showing in Data Studio.
Wanted to show Cumulative %Utilisation by team & yearmonth wise.
To help further with respect to calculation its booked hours/ effective capacity hours = Utilisation %
E.g. Where Feb's % will be total booked hours for Jan+Feb for Team PPP / Total effective capacity hours for Jan+Feb for Team PPP = Team PPP's Utilisation %

it would be useful to know what the incorrect value is as this will help with debugging

I went through some of the articles where they have mentioned that it is a limitation of Data Studio for Column charts. Cumulative numbers are only applicable for Line Charts.
